# Creating Class Objects from Static Functions

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, instance, static-variables

Suppose I have a code as following.

```
class Color
{
static Color a;
public:
static Color newColor(int r,int g,int b){
        Color color;
        color.setR(r);
        color.setG(g);
        color.setB(b);
        return color;
    }
}
```

Is it alright to initialize the static variable 'a' using 'Color a = Color::newColor(255,0,0);'
I think I read somewhere that creating the instance using this method will create two instances of the class. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to port a Java application to C++. The Java class tries to initialize the static variable within the class using 'public static final Color a = newColor(255,0,0);' I just need an way to do that in C++

Comment: as a side note you would probably be better off using the RGB macro, it would be more effective. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162937(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, this looks **really** odd for C++ code. Why have a function initializing an object, instead of having a constructor??

Comment: Also, in C++ everything doesn't have to be a static member of a class. Both functions and variables can be declared on their own!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Color gets instantiated twice

1. the local variable color in newCOlor and
2. the static Color a (since you are returning an object, a member-wise copy will happen at the static variable definition/initialization).

Be sure to put Color::a = Color::newColor(255,0,0); in a cpp/cc file, meaning not in a header file.

Comment: Actually, if you analyze code like this, for example by putting debug statements in the constructors, assignment operators and destructor, you'll see that almost every compiler optimizes away the additional copy / assignment that you would expect to see and instead directly moves the local variable into the assigned variable.

Comment: local variables are allocated from stack though

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size:

```
struct Color
{
    int   R, G, B;
};

Color a = {255, 0, 0};
```